# jQ: Parse localstorage & stringify values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage, stringify

I am storing some values in `localStorage` using `stringify` and I'm trying to parse them but it doesn't work for me.

This is how I add the values:

```
localStorage.setItem('a', JSON.stringify({ userid : '4361', value : '23' }));
```

And this is how I parse them:

```
$('p').text(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('a')));
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hrHfG/

Also, I'd like to know how can I parse each value separately. For example, only the userid of 'a', or only the value, if its possible.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('a'))` returns an object. You cannot use an object like that as an argument in `.text()`.

This works though:

```
$('p').text(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('a')).value);
```

Comment: it doesn't for me... try to alert it

Comment: Hm this works. Can you parse the entire key though? Or is it not useful?

Comment: Then you should just not parse it as an object

Comment: I see what you mean. So then I would parse it as localStorage.getItem('a')