# parsing an object array with JSON in Javascript for local storage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am storing an array of Latlng objects for later use with a map, using local storage, when I use JSON.parse to get and put the values back into an array i get the following error

Uncaught Error: Invalid value for constructor parameter 0: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

my code is:

```
localStorage["positions"] = JSON.stringify(this.positions); //stores array

var stored_positions = JSON.parse(localStorage["positions"]); //get array
```

If i output the stringified array as a string, without parsing i see

```
[{"ob":11,"pb":11},{"ob":11,"pb":12},{"ob":10,"pb":12},{"ob":10,"pb":12}]
```

Comment: And what is in `this.positions`?

Comment: maybe its an object of arrays can you show your json

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your `JSON.parse` line and look at what `localStorage["positions"]` gives you.

Comment: You didn't close the `JSON.parse( ...`

Comment: in this.positions is an array of google map objects - new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

Comment: Shouldn't it be `localStorage.setItem()` and `localStorage.getItem()`?

Comment: What does the dev tools in Chrome or FF show for localStorage? @Andy you can use [] to access localStorage, http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQ: Parse localstorage & stringify values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079380/jq-parse-localstorage-stringify-values)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after a while I still could not manage to retrieve the google map latLng objects, so i stored an array of just the latitude variables and another of just the longitude. turning it back into the object after retrieval .

Drawing lines on the map with this gave slow laggy performance, i turned geodesic to false. and its fast again.